# Run RL Stable_baselines3 SAC model in microcontroller

Tags: stm32, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I have trained a reinforcement learning model (SAC) for the control of the temperature of the shower, and I would like to run it in a microcontroller (STM32H723ZGT6) which my friend is programming in C++. Can I do this? How can we load the model in the microcontroller? Do I have to save it in a special format or set an special parameter during the training to be sure that the micro is able to use it without any problem?

Comment: Maybe you should not have started from a model of your choice, but select from the supported ones. Otherwise you may face a long journey. Have a look [here](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/AI:Introduction_to_Artificial_Intelligence_with_STM32) and [here](https://stm32ai.st.com/stm32-cube-ai/).